# Como gerar um relatório a partir de uma macro gravada?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Boa tarde a todos,
gravei uma macro para gerar um relatório a partir de uma planilha que estou alimentando com dados.
Basicamente a macro vai criar outra pasta de trabalho na mesma planilha e colar os dados na vertical (transpor). Porém, eu preciso voltar a planilha original e copiar outra tabela, aí ao voltar a nova planilha criada a macro dá erro por causa do nome da planilha criada.

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
Sheets("MUNICÍPIO").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
Range("AK5:AN24").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Planilha15").Select
```

A macro dá um erro nessa última linha, pois o arquivo não vai selecionar "Planilha15" denovo. Gostaria de resolver isso fixando o nome da planilha para Relatório, ou mesmo um nome qualquer, só para não ocorrer este erro.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.Workbooks("<nome da sua pasta de trabalho com extensão>").Activate
```

Você também pode apagar isso, é a gravação do scroll do mouse.

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
```